# Offering both asynchronous and synchronous API with a target callback queue

Tags: ios, multithreading, macos, grand-central-dispatch

I am writing a networking API. Since the underlying call to `NSURLSession` is always asynchronous, I offer an asynchronous API by default:

```
- (void) callBackendServerWithCompletion: (dispatch_block_t) completion;
```

It’s also very convenient to offer a synchronous version of this API, for example to simplify testing the code in Xcode playgrounds. The synchronous call is written in terms of the asynchronous one:

```
- (void) callBackendSynchronously
{
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    [self callBackendServerWithCompletion:^{
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
```

This works fine.

Now I would like to add an extra convenience feature, a default dispatch queue to call the completion blocks on. This callback queue defaults to the UI queue, so that the consumer of this API doesn’t have to `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{…})` all the time:

```
// This:
[webservice callBackendServerWithCompletion:^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self updateUI];
    });
}];

// Would be replaced with this:
[webservice callBackendServerWithCompletion:^{
    // Guaranteed to run on the main queue
    [self updateUI];
}];
```

This was fairly easy to do, but now I have a deadlock when calling the synchronous method on the main queue:

1. `-callBackendSynchronously` calls `-callBackendServerWithCompletion` and waits on the semaphore.
2. The asynchonous method processes the network request and dispatches the callback on the main queue.
3. Since the main queue is already waiting for the semaphore, the code deadlocks.

What’s a simple way to offer all three features, ie. both synchronous & asynchronous API methods and a default callback queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a private, overloaded version of `callBackendServerWithCompletion` accepting a dispatch queue. In `callBackendSynchronously`call this new overloaded method with a custom background queue.

And, finally, in your original`callBackendServerWithCompletion` method call the overloaded version passing the default queue as parameter.

Comment: @zoul  Good to hear!

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround was to add the callback queue not as a property, but as an argument for the async call:

```
/// Guaranteed to call the completion on the main queue
- (void) callBackendServerWithCompletion: (dispatch_block_t) completion;
/// Pick your own callback queue
- (void) callBackendServerWithTargetQueue: (dispatch_queue_t) callbackQueue completion: (dispatch_block_t) completion;
```

Then the synchronous method may specify a global queue for the callback, breaking the deadlock because the semaphore is signalled from another thread:

```
- (void) callBackendSynchronously
{
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    [self callBackendServerWithCallbackQueue:dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0) completion:^{
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    }];
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
```

I’m not yet sure if there are some drawbacks.

Comment: I believe this is deadlock free even if the calling code is using the same global queue, right? (i.e., this holds because the global queue is *concurrent*.)

Answer (score 1):

Implementing your synchronous API like that will cause problems with QOS and Importance inheritance.  I strongly suggest that you change your paradigm to avoid using semaphores wherever possible.  Assuming you have an operation queue that you serialize your operations on, you can do something like this:

```
-(void)doItAsyncWithCompletionHandler:(nullable void (^)(NSError * _Nullable error)completionHandler
{
    [self doItAsyncWithCompletionQueue:nil completionHandler:completionHandler];
}

-(void)doItAsyncWithCompletionQueue:(nullable dispatch_queue_t)completionQueue
                  completionHandler:(nullable void (^)(NSError * _Nullable error)completionHandler
{
    if (!completionQueue) {
        completionQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qos_class_self(), 0);
    }

    completionHandler = completionHandler.copy;

    dispatch_async(self.operationQueue, ^{
        NSError *error;
        BOOL success = [self _onOperationQueueDoItWithError:&error];
        NSAssert((success && !error) || (!success && error), @"API Contract violation in -_onOperationQueueDoItWithError:");

        if (completionHandler) {
            dispatch_async(completionQueue, ^{
                completionHandler(error);
            });
        }
    });
}

-(BOOL)doItSyncWithError:(NSError * __autoreleasing _Nullable * _Nullable)error
{
    __block BOOL success;

    dispatch_sync(self.operationQueue, ^{
        success = [self _onOperationQueueDoItWithError:error];
    });

    return success;
}

-(BOOL)_onOperationQueueDoItWithError:(NSError * __autoreleasing _Nullable * _Nullable)error
{
    dispatch_assert_queue(self.operationQueue);

    ...
}
```

Comment: The synchronous API is mostly used for testing and playgrounds, so it’s not a big issue, but thank you anyway! I didn’t know about this stuff.